# write a query in t-sql that compares 2 characters of the same column

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

Query to list all the names where first and second name starts with same character.There is only a single column for name i.e., name that has diffrent name formats like 'sivani   naga','naga sivani','sivani sivu'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: thank you I will try not to include this kind of quesions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should meet the requirements. It is a take on @Luis Gutierrez's answer however to make it easier to read (in my opinion) I have reduced the amount of calls to the [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function by using a subquery which returns all the names and the first letter of the first and last names in as a table in itself, then I select all from that sub table. I think this looks nicer because then I can use the column aliases set in the subquery in the where clause instead of more calls the substring function.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (whole_name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 'sivani naga'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 'naga sivani'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 'sivani sivu'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 'a a'
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 'a b'

SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT whole_name, 
               SUBSTRING(whole_name, 1, 1) 
                      first_name_letter, 
               SUBSTRING(whole_name, CHARINDEX(' ', whole_name, 1) + 1, 1) 
                      last_name_letter 
        FROM   @tbl) AS newTable 
WHERE  first_name_letter = last_name_letter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Declare @table table (name varchar(100))

 insert into @table Select 'sivani naga'
 insert into @table Select 'naga sivani'
 insert into @table Select 'sivani sivu'


 select *,
 SUBSTRING(name,1,1) name,
 SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name,1)+1,1) lastName 
 from @table where SUBSTRING(name,1,1) = SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name,1)+1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  Substring(colname, 1, 1) = Substring(
                                    Ltrim(
                                        Substring(
                                            colname, 
                                            Charindex(' ', colname), 
                                            Charindex(' ', Ltrim( 
                                                Substring(
                                                    colname, 
                                                    Charindex(' ', colname), 
                                                    Len(colname) - Charindex(' ', colname)
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ), 1, 1)
```